# Configure output of Visual Studio 2019 Paste XML as Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

When using Edit->Paste Special-Paste Xml as Classes, the generated output is like so:

```
public class RootElement
{
    private string prop1Field;
    private string  prop2Field;

    public string Prop1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.prop1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.prop1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Prop2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.prop2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.prop2Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to configure this behaviour so it instead creates something more concise like this?

```
public class RootElement
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure that behaviour.

My guess is that they are doing it because [autoimplemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) "only" made apppearence in c# as far as c# 3.0 so they came up with a solution that is not c# version dependant (backwards compatibility). I know no way of forcing that special paste to use them, but I would love it to.

Comment: I expected as much because I expected it to be in the Options menu. It's just so verbose that it creates issues. But anyway. Thanks for the answer.